# RegQueryValueEx returning a different value every time

Tags: c++, registry

I'm trying to read a registry key value and display it. I created myself the key i'm currently trying to read, and set it's value to "foo" using regedit :

```
HKEY hkey;
DWORD dwret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes\\foo", NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hkey);

if (dwret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{

    TCHAR value[1024] = _T("");
    DWORD dwvalue = 1024;
    DWORD type = REG_SZ;

    RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes\\test", NULL,&type , (LPBYTE)&value, &dwvalue);
    cout << value;

    RegCloseKey(hkey);
    hkey = NULL;
}
```

The problem is, I'm always getting a different output if I run my code multiple times, here's an extract :

```
00CFF5D0
001CF2D8
005EF5B8
0053F5A4
```

Did I misunderstand something ? Isn't RegQueryValueEx supposed to store key value into my `value` ? If yes, why do I get a different output every time ?

Comment: Did you check that the call to [`RegQueryValueEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa) was successful? And what is the type of the value? And why do you pass the name of a *key* as the name of the value? And why do you pass `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of the handle to the key you just opened (i.e. `hkey`)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is clearly being compiled for Unicode, such that `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` and `RegQueryValueEx()` maps to `RegQueryValueExW()`.

But `std::cout` does not have an `operator<<` for a `wchar_t*` pointer as input, but it does have an `operator<<` for a `void*` pointer, which prints out the memory address contained in the pointer.

ANY pointer can be implicitly converted to `void*`, so that is the `overator<<` overload you are actually calling, which is why you are seeing hex numbers in your output.

You get different values each time you run your code because your `value[]` buffer is located at different memory addresses each time.

To account for this, you need to either:

- use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` when `UNICODE` is defined:

  ```
  #ifdef UNICODE
  wcout << value;
  #else
  cout << value;
  #endif
  ```

  Alternatively:

  ```
  #ifdef UNICODE
  wostream &tcout = wcout;
  #else
  ostream &tcout = cout;
  #endif

  tcout << value;
  ```
- convert your `value` buffer from `wchar_t` to `char`, such as with `WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivilent, before then outputting it with `std::cout`:

  ```
  #ifdef UNICODE
  char temp[1024];
  int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, value, -1, temp, sizeof(temp)-1, NULL, NULL);
  temp[len] = 0;
  cout << temp;
  #else
  cout << value;
  #endif
  ```
- use `RegQueryValueExA()` with a `char[]` buffer, instead of using `RegQueryValueEx()` with a `TCHAR[]` buffer.  Let the OS handle the conversion to `char[]` for you:

  ```
  char value[1024];
  ...
  RegQueryValueExA(..., (LPBYTE)&value, ...);
  ...
  cout << value;
  ```

That being said, there are several other problems with your code, as well.

1. You are using `TCHAR` based APIs, but you are using hard-coded **wide** string literals.  That will only work if you set your project to compile for Unicode (which you should be).  But to be *politically correct*, you should be using the `TEXT()` macro when using string literals with `TCHAR` APIs.

   ```
   TEXT("Software\\Classes\\foo")
   TEXT("test")
   ...
   ```

   However, you really shouldn't be using `TCHAR` APIs at all anymore.  They were introduced way back in the early days when Windows was still an ANSI-based OS migrating to Unicode.  `TCHAR` helped developers support both ANSI and Unicode versions of the OS.  But those days are LONG gone.  Stick with Unicode APIs only, except when you absolutely need ANSI APIs.  Forget that `TCHAR` exists.
2. Your call to `RegQueryValueEx()` is all wrong.

   - You are not doing any error checking to make sure `RegQueryValueEx()` actually succeeds before you use the `value` buffer.

     ```
     dwret = RegQueryValueEx(...);
     if (dwret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
         ...
     else
         ...
     ```
   - You cannot pass a key path in its `lpValueName` parameter, only a value name.  Assuming your `foo` key has a `test` value, you need to pass in the `hkey` that you opened, and specify just `"test"` as the value name:

     ```
     DWORD dwret = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Classes\\foo"), NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hkey);
     if (dwret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
     {
         ...
         dwret = RegQueryValueEx(hkey, TEXT("test"), ...);
         ...
     }
     ```
   - You are passing in the wrong size value for the `lpcbData` parameter.  That parameter is expressed in **bytes**, but the size you are passing in is expressed in **characters**.  And since your code is being compiled for Unicode, where `sizeof(TCHAR)` is 2, that means `RegQueryValueEx()` can write to only half of your buffer.  Use `sizeof()` to get the full byte size:

     ```
     DWORD dwvalue = sizeof(value);
     ```
   - You are not taking into account that the returned string MIGHT NOT be null-terminated, even if `RegQueryValueEx()` succeeds.  For simple tests with small manual strings, it will likely be null terminated, but in production code, you need to handle the possibility that the null terminator MIGHT NOT always be present.  Otherwise, use [`RegGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew) instead, which ensures a null terminator is ALWAYS in the output, even if it is not present in the source data.
3. You are passing your `value` buffer to `std::cout` regardless of whether `RegQueryValueEx()` succeeds or fails.  If `RegQueryValueEx()` fails, the contents of the buffer will be indeterminate, and not guaranteed to be null terminated, so don't use the buffer at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```
HKEY hkey = NULL;
LONG lret = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes\\foo", NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hkey);
if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    WCHAR value[1024] = {};
    DWORD dwvalue = sizeof(value);
    DWORD type = REG_SZ;

    lret = RegQueryValueExW(hkey, L"test", NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &dwvalue);
    if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        int len = (dwvalue / sizeof(WCHAR));
        if ((len > 0) && (value[len-1] == 0))
            --len;

        wcout.write(value, len);

        /* alternatively:
        char temp[1024];
        len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, value, len, temp, sizeof(temp), NULL, NULL);
        cout.write(temp, len);
        */
    }

    RegCloseKey(hkey);
    hkey = NULL;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
HKEY hkey = NULL;
LONG lret = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Classes\\foo", NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hkey);
if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    CHAR value[1024] = {};
    DWORD dwvalue = sizeof(value);
    DWORD type = REG_SZ;

    lret = RegQueryValueExA(hkey, "test", NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&value, &dwvalue);
    if (lret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if ((dwvalue > 0) && (value[dwvalue-1] == 0))
            --dwvalue;

        cout.write(value, dwvalue);
    }

    RegCloseKey(hkey);
    hkey = NULL;
}
```